# Планирование структуры базы данных для базы знаний по игре, что будет эффективнее?

Tags: база-данных, django, postgresql

Предисловие, есть готовый сайт на `django` с базой знаний по игре. Под капотом категории в базе знаний реализованы в отдельных таблицах `postgresql` c полями описание объекта и набором свойств для сравнения которые для каждой категории свои.

Пока категорий в базе не очень большое количество, и соответственно можно ее безболезненно переделать.

Хочу унифицировать объекты в базе в одну таблицу с полем описания объекта и и.д., а свойства и их значения вынести в две отдельные таблицы. После чего просто делать связь объекта со свойствами и их значениями.

Вопрос в том стоит ли это делать? И есть ли какие то другие варианты решения задачи?

upd.

Вот какую схему базы данных я имел виду, взял ее с онлайн магазина.

Модель категории, например: Оружие(подкатегория Мечи), Зелья, Доспепи и т.д.

```
class Category(MPTTModel, ModerationBaseModel):
    """
    Category of item
    extend ItemBaseModel
    which has slug, name,
    description, keywords
    """
    slug = models.CharField(
        _("Slug"),
        default="",
        unique=True,
        max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(
        _("Description"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    keywords = models.CharField(
        _("Keywords"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='children',
        verbose_name=_('Parent'))
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='category_images/',
        blank=True,
        default="",
        verbose_name=_('Image'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Categories')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

Модель для страницы в базе знаний, например: "меч Ледяная Скорбь"

```
class Item(ModerationBaseModel):
    slug = models.CharField(
        _("Slug"),
        default="",
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
        max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(
        _("Title"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(
        _("Description"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    keywords = models.CharField(
        _("Keywords"),
        blank=True,
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='Itemimeges/',
        blank=True,
        default="",
        verbose_name=_('Image'))
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='categories',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Category'))
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,)
    full_text = models.TextField(blank=True,)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.category:
            super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            # we create properties if not exist
            for cp in CategoryProperty.objects.filter(category=self.category):
                pp = ItemProperty.objects.filter(category_property=cp,
                                                 Item=self)
                if not pp:
                    pp = ItemProperty(category_property=cp,
                                      Item=self, value="--")
                    pp.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Item')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Items')
```

Модель для набора свойств в определенной категории, например: Категория Мечи - свойства урон, скорость, дпс и т.д.

```
class CategoryProperty(ModerationBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='categories_property',
        verbose_name=_('Category'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Category property')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Category properties')
```

И последняя модель для хранения значений свойств конкретного объекта, например: "Ледяная Скорбь" - урон - 100, скорость - 20, дпс - 500.

```
class ItemProperty(ModerationBaseModel):
    category_property = models.ForeignKey(
        CategoryProperty,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='category_property',
        verbose_name=_('Propery'))
    value = models.CharField(
        _("Value"),
        default="",
        max_length=250)
    Item = models.ForeignKey(
        'Item',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='properties_Item',
        verbose_name=_('Item'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Item property')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Item properties')
```

Но получается что если в категории 100 страниц а у каждой страницы 10 свойств, выходит 100*10 = 1000 записей в базе данных, и еще плюс 10 других категорий 1000*10 = 10000 записей (при нынешней реализации это будет просто 1000 записей и 10 различных моделей для каждой категории).

Но при подходе с унифицированными страницами и отдельными свойствами (который я описал выше) все управление данными ведется с админки и добавляя новые категории не нужно править код моделей. Вот у меня и вопрос стоит ли все это того?

И еще я знаю реализации магазинов где категории товаров также жестко прописываются в моделях, вот пример [Заготовка под магазин django-SHOP](http://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/simple-product.html)

За пример беру магазины, поскольку база знаний этот тот же самый магазин только без корзины =).

Comment: То есть есть таблицы под оружие, доспехи, зелья и т.п. и хочется свести все в одну? А в чем польза?

Comment: Да все так, смысл в том что для добавления новой категории нужно создавать новую модель делать миграции и т.д.. То есть с админки это сделать невозможно. Я вот и думаю стоит переделывать ли нет.

Comment: Еще ситуация, какое то свойство устаревает или нужно добавить новое , и опять же нужно править саму модель и удалять/добавлять поля в базе данных

Answer (score 1):

> Да все так, смысл в том что для добавления новой категории нужно создавать новую модель делать миграции и т.д.

Не обязательно.
Делаешь модель, например, "зелья".

```
class Зелье(models.Model):
     название = CharField()


class Свойство(models.Model):
    свойство = Charfield(choices=типы_свойств)
    процент_изменения = FloatField()
    зелье = ForeignKey("Зелья")
```

Ну и всё. Дальше создаёшь этих зелий из админки, сколько угодно.

Comment: А как сравнить например два зелья если у них могут быть разные поля свойств при таком подходе. Я добавил код выше который я имел в виду.

Comment: @Bogdan Ivanchenko, по категориям свойств, конечно. Посмотри, что такое `choices'.